# How to download PrimeFaces showcase?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I am trying to learn PrimeFaces. For this I think its showcase would be the good way to start.
But I want to run this offline, like we can download showcase for struts and run it. Same I want to download the showcase of PrimesFaces.

But I couldn't find the direct link. Help me out with this.

Also recommend me some good book to get deep knowledge about primeFaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here it is, you can grab it from [primefaces repository](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/)

[primefaces/showcase/](https://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/showcase/)

Regarding the book/ knowledge base, take a look at the [Documentation Section](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html), you will find lots of info about primefaces over there.

Answer (score 1):

You can see more details about how can you use it at http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/download-primefaces-showcase-and-source-code/